# Laravel passing variables inside route accessing a named route

Tags: php, laravel, variables, routes

I am trying to pass 3 variables values inside an html  link that uses route to access a named routed with this code:

```
<a href="{{ route('gegonota', ['gid' => $gid,'cid' => $cid , 'nid' => $nid]) }}">{{$nomos->name}}</a>
```

also the route function is

```
Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?}/{nid?}', ['uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 'as' => 'gegonota']);
```

but it doesnt work right.
How can i do it.
thanks

Comment: show the error what you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
<a href="{{ route('gegonota', [ $gid,$cid , $nid]) }}">{{$nomos->name}}</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it was great help but now there is another problem, when i pass a null variable (with null value) it gives me the error (1/1) NotFoundHttpException. 
e.g. one of the variables is null as it should be as they are defined optional in Route (Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?})  but whern i call the route   gegonota/1//0  (the second is null gives the error i talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `?` from your routes params so it will be :

```
Route::get('gegonota/{gid}/{cid}/{nid}', [
'uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 
'as' => 'gegonota'
]);
```

if you want to use `?` you need to provide a default value check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters)

and if you use **Laravel v5.4** you need to change your route to :

```
Route::get('gegonota/{gid}/{cid}/{nid}', [
  'uses' => 'GegonosController@index' 
])->name('gegonota');
```

Comment: i tried to give null values in optional variables in route but gives error. The code is
Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?}/{nid?}', function ($gid = null,$cid = null,$nid = null) {
    return $gid $cid $nid;
    } ,
['uses' => 'GegonosController@index', 'as' => 'gegonota']);

Comment: i changed in that

Route::get('gegonota/{gid?}/{cid?}/{nid?}', function ($gid = null,$cid = null,$nid = null) {
    return $gid, $cid, $nid;
    },['uses' => 'GegonosController@index'])->name('gegonota');

and gives me the  error  syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: you need to define the default values of your params in the index method not in a inline function since you are using a controller not closure

Comment: ok i have already did that earlier 
public function index($gid = null, $cid = null, $nid = null)
    {
and gives me the error


(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 548)

Comment: Check your routes and middlewares with php artisan route:list.